# tmux not updating zsh_history anymore

Tags: zsh, tmux

My distro recently got updated by our support group, which updated tmux. I used to have the following nice behavior: If I run a command in pane A, switch to pane B, press Enter once, I get the command in the history of pane B (i.e. by pressing up arrow once). Now, the history of the panes seem disjoint, and a command from pane A will only appear in other panes if they are created after running the command.

Is there an option to fix this to the old behavior?